# Insert image from SQL into crystal reports

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I have a c# winform app that stores images in an sql database as "image".
I can store the image just fine but when a print the report the image does not appear. I searched for a solution but none of the provided fixes my issue.

EDIT:  (solution)

I found that the source of the problem was the image insert code. 
I was inserting data but it was corrupted.

```
       using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.temp (larg, ...maquete) VALUES ('" + larg.Text + "','" ... @photo)", con))
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pictureBox2.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] photo = ms.ToArray();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo);
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: You mean image from DB to CReport?

Comment: Hi, yes. From DB to CReport